# change Leaflet circleMarker ,to any custom icon (large data)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

[image]
I load about 10K `L.circleMarker` on the **leaflet map** and its works great.
I try to change the **icon of the circle to anything but I cant**
I know that I can change the icon in the regular marker but I don't, know how can I change the `L.circleMarker`.

can't find any doc about changing circle markers:
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker

I want to get a result something like this but with different shapes of circle markers:
[image]

**ill be thankful if you have any experience to share**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cant change CircleMarker Shape so, we have to use marker but markers are heavy to load +10K marker so we should change them to path or canvas or font we have a very cool LIB that does this for us and solves my problem loading +250K marker with custom shape and coordinate.

here is the GitHub reference :
https://github.com/eJuke/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers
[image: sample data picture loaded with cnavas]

CODE

```
<script src="leaflet-markers-canvas.js"></script>  
           var markersCanvas = new L.MarkersCanvas();
                 markersCanvas.addTo(map);
        //DO what you want to do with marker
   var icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "images/black_gps.png",
        iconSize: [15, 15],
        iconAnchor: [10, 0],
    });
          var marker = new L.Marker([latitude,longitude],{icon}); 
        markersCanvas.addMarkers(markers);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible for L.circleMarker to load an icon directly. I have
> been in similar situation and used a bit of hack combining L.circle
> and L.marker. I need to specify radius in meters didn't know how to
> convert it to pixels. L.circleMarker allows to specify Radius of the
> circle marker, in pixels. L.circle allows to specify Radius of the
> circle, in meters.

try this function to set leftlet icon to any other icon :

You can take detailed reference from here (**https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon**)

```
function setLeafLetIcon(icon, marker) {
        var myIconReplc = L.Icon.extend({
            options: {
                iconUrl: icon, // icon image url here
                iconSize: [20, 24],
                iconAnchor: [10, 24]

            }
        });
        marker.setIcon(new myIconReplc);
    
}
```

Comment: the problem is that setIcon can be set for Marker, not Circle marker.
and cant load 200K data with marker it will crash the explorer.